# C# - Windows Server - A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception

Tags: wcf, authentication, windows-10, tls1.2

I have the following solution :

WCF service hosted in Windows Service
WCF configurated to use TCP

After i updated Windows Server, i receive this error from my code:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost)
   at Counterpoint.Irina.Services.ServerConnector.ConnectorBaseSsl..ctor(String ipServer, Int32 port) in 
---------- Inner Exception ----------
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
One or more of the parameters passed to the function was invalid
```

My programs is in C# and i use a TcpClient with SslStream in this way :

```
_connection = new TcpClient(ipServer, port);   
sslStream = new SslStream(_connection.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateReceived));
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(ipServer);
```

And this is the code of RemoteCertificate

```
// The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
// This allows you to check the certificate and accept or reject it
// return true will accept the certificate
private static bool CertificateReceived(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
        return true;

}
```

**Update:**

The error on eventviewver is 
"The following fatal alert was generated: 40. The internal error state is 808."

**Update 2**

The problem is the update KG3172605
https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/kb/3172605

Please help :)